# How to get WooCommerce cart subtotal value?

Tags: php, woocommerce

I am currently trying to make an `if else` check in the checkout of a WooCommerce site.

I need to know if the total is greater or less than 100, so that it will say "*You need to call to negotiate a shipping fee*".

The code:

```
$woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total()
```

shows the value, but adds HTML content.

I need only the value itself.

Answer (score 4):

I kind of found out how to do this the hard way.

I searched google for over 2 hours and found this page: https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_cartget_cart_subtotal/

```
global $woocommerce;
$subtotal = $woocommerce->cart->get_subtotal();
$subtax = $woocommerce->cart->get_subtotal_tax();
$subtotaltax = $subtotal+$subtax;
```

echo with $subtotaltax shows the value with the tax added.